ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyheif, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based
Here's the post in English for Stack Overflow:
**Error building pyheif package in Docker on Mac OS (works on Windows)
I'm developing a Python application using Docker with Python 3.12. The application works fine on Windows, but when trying to build it on Mac OS, I encounter an error when installing the pyheif package. The error is related to a missing header file libheif/heif.h:
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.7/_libheif_cffi.c:570:15: fatal error: libheif/heif.h: No such file or directory

Here’s my Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12

ENV MODE=testing

EXPOSE 8000

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements/ ./requirements/

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y gettext libheif-dev && \
    pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN pip3 install -r requirements/development.txt

RUN mkdir media && mkdir basemod && mkdir main && mkdir templates && mkdir static && mkdir config && mkdir locale && mkdir logs

COPY manage.py ./
COPY secrets.json ./

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

I've already tried the following:

Ensured the libheif-dev package is installed in the Docker image.
Checked that libheif is available via Homebrew on Mac by running brew install libheif.
Verified that I have the latest Xcode command-line tools with xcode-select --install.

This works perfectly on Windows but fails on Mac OS. How can I resolve the issue with the missing libheif/heif.h on Mac in Docker? Any suggestions would be appreciated!
Make sure to adapt this post to include any further specific details about your setup if needed!

Install libheif to your machine before install pyheif https://github.com/strukturag/libheif try compiling with yourself

as damp1113 said install libheif first.
For macOS:

Install dependencies with Homebrew
brew install cmake make pkg-config x265 libde265 libjpeg libtool

Configure and build project (--preset argument needs CMake >= 3.21):
cd build
cmake --preset=release ..
./configure
make




https://github.com/strukturag/libheif?tab=readme-ov-file#macos
For mac in Docker: https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/47#issuecomment-899575287

haw it integrate in docker ?

Check this out : https://github.com/carsales/pyheif/issues/47#issuecomment-899575287

My docker file look like this. This code work on MacBook
FROM python:3.12

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        make \
        pkg-config \
        libx265-dev \
        libde265-dev \
        libjpeg-dev \
        libtool \
        git \
        build-essential \
        wget \
        gnupg

RUN wget https://cmake.org/files/v3.22/cmake-3.22.1.tar.gz && \
    tar -xzvf cmake-3.22.1.tar.gz && \
    cd cmake-3.22.1 && \
    ./bootstrap && \
    make && \
    make install

RUN git clone https://github.com/strukturag/libheif.git /libheif && \
    cd /libheif && \
    mkdir build && \
    cd build && \
    cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release .. && \
    make && \
    make install

COPY requirements/ /app/requirements/
WORKDIR /app/requirements

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r development.txt

COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "manage.py", "", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

